# Tool for Multiple Code Deployments.

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

Sorry if a similar question has been posed before.  There are a lot of deployment questions but none seemed to address my problem.

Anyway.  I'm working with asp.net, C# and using Visual Studio.

The Organization I'm working in is changing rapidly.  There are a lot of projects coming in the pipeline that will require multiple code changes and iterative deployments over the next few months.  While working, these changes are always 'on the forefront', so sometimes I have to code certain parts of the same program multiple times.

Since these projects are all staggered, I can't just make one sweeping change all at once; I have to deploy and redeploy the same program multiple times, using only the changes that are required for that deployment.

If this is confusing, here's a simple example:

- Application is being used on an Intranet.  This application calls our Database, using Driver A.
- There are two environments, test and production.
- Certain Stored procedures have to be called with parameters that register 'Test' to allow certain other applications to run even with bad data (for testing purposes).
- When deploying applications, these stored procedures have to be modified, removing Test parameters
- We have an Operating System upgrade, allowing us to move to a much faster Driver B, but requires changes to be made to the code to use Driver B.

So that's two wholly different deployments where some code must be changed for Deployment 1 and other code must be changed for Deployment 2.

Currently I'm just using notepad for an overall change list, regular debugging break points and a multitude of in-code comments, and then I manually slog through the code to make sure that everything is changed.  With hundreds of thousands of lines of code over multiple files, classes, objects, etc. this gets pretty tedious, as well as there being a good chance of missing something (causing it to break) or pushing wrong changes (causing it to either break or allow bad data).

Is there a tool that could be used to help in this situation?  Preferably one that I can discern what needs to change for Deployment A and what needs to change for Deployment B?  I'm also open to hearing other schools of thought as well (tips are definitely accepted!)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I understand your problem.

I would suggest a couple of things

1. Installers : Why don't you think of installers, there are loads of installers i.e Install shield, Wix, MSI installer.
   These installers will give you flexibilty to update files which you need to update, i.e. Full Control.
   But you need to choose the best of them, I have worked around MSI and Wix a lot, so I know this can sort your problem, however its your call.
2. Publish : I haven't played around much with this, I have just done website publish. However I know it does wonders, so try it also.